# Using JavaFX, how do you get values from a slider?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to use JavaFX to create sliders using SceneBuilder and then assigning those values to integers. 
I already created all the sliders that I need, set the `fx:id` correctly as well as set the correct controller class.

Here is a couple snippets of code that I am having trouble with.

```
@FXML private Slider hMinSlider;
```

and then I have this piece of code

```
if(hMinSlider == null) {
    minH = 0;
}else{ 
    minH = (int)hMinSlider.getValue();
}
```

The problem is that `hMinSlider` is always null. Is there an extra step to this that I am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code should work fine, assuming it is in the correct context. Post a [MCVE].

Comment: @James_D Sorry that its taking so long but I've been trying to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example but I am unable to recreate the problem accurately while keeping everything that should be the same.